# How to create customised release strategy for aggregator in Spring Integration using dsl?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a scenario where i don't want to use default release strategy for aggregator . I want to create customised aggregator release strategy .

UPDATE : Updated Integration flow :

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileIntegrationFlow(){
        return IntegrationFlows.from(readFilefromDirectory(), fileInboundPollingConsumer())
                .split(fileSplitter())
                .filter(p -> !(p instanceof FileSplitter.FileMarker), 
                        f -> f.discardChannel("passToAggregate"))
                        .transform(dataDataTransformer())
                        .filter(fileFilter())
                        .wireTap(logChannel())
                        .channel("passToAggregate")
                        .aggregate(a->a.releaseStrategy(group ->
                        group.getMessages()
                        .stream()
                        .anyMatch(m ->
                        FileSplitter.FileMarker.Mark.END.name()
                        .equals(m.getHeaders().get(FileHeaders.MARKER)))))
                        .wireTap(logChannel())
                        .<List<Customer>>handle((p, h) -> new MonitoringData(p))
                        .transform(Transformers.marshaller(getMarshaller(),resultTransformer(),true))
                        .handle(fileWriter()).get();

    }
```

Now in logs i can see customer objects when i removed `correlationstrategy` :

```
[FileMarker [filePath=D:\example_tex\in\dateeea.txt, mark=START], com.springintegration.example.Customer@470aa1cb, com.springintegration.example.Customer@7c898288, FileMarker [filePath=D:\example_tex\in\dateeea.txt, mark=END, lineCount=6]]
```

Now i will start to work on output processor to filter data.

Comment: I don't receive any notification when you edit your question. Please, consider to add some comment for my answer to notify me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should be familiar with all the Aggregator options and strategies. For this purpose you should take a look to the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator).

After that you can just follow with the auto-completion on the `AggregatorSpec` configuring your `.aggregate()`. The custom `releaseStrategy` can be achieved via these methods:

```
/**
 * Configure the handler with an {@link ExpressionEvaluatingReleaseStrategy} for the
 * given expression.
 * @param releaseExpression the correlation expression.
 * @return the handler spec.
 * @see AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler#setReleaseStrategy(ReleaseStrategy)
 */
public S releaseExpression(String releaseExpression) {
...
/**
 * Configure the handler with an
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.aggregator.MethodInvokingReleaseStrategy}
 * for the target object and method name.
 * @param target the target object.
 * @param methodName the method name.
 * @return the handler spec.
 * @see AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler#setReleaseStrategy(ReleaseStrategy)
 */
public S releaseStrategy(Object target, String methodName) {
...
/**
 * @param releaseStrategy the release strategy.
 * @return the handler spec.
 * @see AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler#setReleaseStrategy(ReleaseStrategy)
 */
public S releaseStrategy(ReleaseStrategy releaseStrategy) {
...
```

For your use-case with the `FileSplitter` and allow to release group when the `Mark.END` has arrived, I'd suggest this implementation:

```
.releaseStrategy(group ->
      group.getMessages()
             .stream()
             .anyMatch(m ->
                   FileSplitter.FileMarker.Mark.END.name()
                               .equals(m.getHeaders().get(FileHeaders.MARKER))))
```

Comment: You haven't finished your work there. You don't enable markers on the `FileSplitter`. Also you have to filter `FileSplitter.FileMarker` from the output list of the `.aggregate()`. Consider the custom `outputProcessor`

Comment: That's logical. Isn't it? Now you have a new payload, but the same transformer. I suggest you to add `.filter()` before your transformer to discard markers directly to aggregator. See an approach in my answer to your other question.

Comment: Can you explain outputprocessor why required here ? what i understood is that after aggregator FileMarker will also be added so we need to remove from aggregator output

Comment: Correct. I provided for you `handle((p, h) -> new MonitoringData(p))`, but that, actually, can be done in the `MessageGroupProcessor`, particularly `AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor`, where you should iterate `MessageGroup`, remove `FileMarker` and build your `MonitoringData` as an output of the aggregator.

Comment: After aggregator when i put log i get this [FileMarker [filePath=D:\example_tex\in\dateeea.txt, mark=END, lineCount=6]] is it correct ? i am thinking like where is my customer objects ?

Comment: I think your problem is `correlationStrategy(m ->m.getHeaders().get("id")`. Since `applySequence = true` is by default in the `AbstractMessageSplitter`, you should just rely on the default `correlationStrategy`, which is `HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID)`

Comment: You config still has some flaws. I believe that `fileMarkerChannel` should be `passToAggregate`. If `Customer`s aren't added then your ` .filter(fileFilter())` just drops them!

Comment: i have added filemarkerchannel as well , is it not correct configured?

Comment: Yes, your `markTransformationFlow` looks good, but we don't need it. We can just discard marker from the filter directly to `passToAggregate` channel. Look, in that flow you just `bridge` from one channel to another. But, eh, sometime that might be useful to extend that discard flow for more logic. OK with me.

Comment: Oh! My bad. I see now. `FileSplitter` does `setApplySequence(false);` if `markers == true`. Try to specify `setApplySequence(true)` explicitly. And will think here one more time why we can't make it by default...

Comment: Now i have removed correlation strategy and in logs i can see customer objects in aggregator output .

Comment: it contains marker start and then two customer objects and marker end in list . so far it looks good  but filtering of markers is required .

Comment: I think you can achieve that with `.transform()` and Java 8 Stream API.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You do pretty straightforward operation with data in the memory. Whatever is easier for you.

Comment: i have one concern that file data may be big like 1 million will it be good to use this solution to write xml file

Comment: No, but that is a different story and we have to come back to our original idea in your another question about custom header/footer Strings for `FileMarker`s.

Comment: Well, I was so interested in your sample that did this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/pull/118

Comment: Thanks i checked that .its Good.